# How to set orderInCategory dynamically?

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

How do i set orderInCategory on creating menu items dynamically. The menu items that i create dynamically always comes to the left of the previously created menu items ( created in xml ).

The menu that i am creating dynamically is a ActionBarSherlock overflow menu.

```
 SubMenu overflowMenu = menu.addSubMenu("Action Item");
         overflowMenu.add(0,SUBMENU_ABOUT,Menu.NONE,"About");
         overflowMenu.add(0,SUBMENU_HELP,Menu.NONE,"Help");
         overflowMenu.add(0,SUBMENU_REPORT,Menu.NONE,"Send Report");
         overflowMenu.add(0,SUBMENU_LOGBOOK,Menu.NONE,"LogBook");




            MenuItem subMenu1Item = overflowMenu.getItem();
            subMenu1Item.setIcon(R.drawable.overflow_menu_trans);
```

So how to put this icon to the rightmost point in the menu? Right now, it comes to the left of what has already been placed in xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_register"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@drawable/action_register"
        android:title="@string/menu_register"/>
</menu>
```

Comment: Examine the ActionBarSherlock source code to see how ActionBarSherlock gets it on the right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@CommonsWare gave this answer. Actually to set the items to the rightmost, i have to set the orderInCategory to a higher value and i was setting it to a lower value. Dynamically, it can be done as

```
SubMenu overflowMenu=menu.addSubMenu(0, MENU_ID, 300, "Action Item");
```

where 300 is the orderId to be set to a higher value then the orderInCategory for menu.xml